# Pyhon (v2.7) requires to install plugins

Tags: python-2.7

I installed Ubuntu very first time over Window 7, but when I played a MP3 song it shows a  "Python (v2.7) requires to install plug in to play media files" message. What to do? Help me!
I have searched over the internet but found nothing there...

Comment: Try to run `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: This will also install all other media codecs provided by GStreamer. (e.g. x264)

Answer (score 1):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal.
2. Write the following in terminal followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`
3. A prompt will ask for password, after entering the password type `y` for yes when asked. Wait for the installation process to over.
4. Now try to run the MP3.

Answer (score 1):

Try to update your repositories and then install ubuntu restricted extras.To do this run the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning you need to update the system before you install, since this seems to be a fresh installation.